# mysql-connector is showing error

Tags: python, mysql

1. I installed mysql-server. It doesn't ask password or username but it is installed.
2. Then I installed mysql-connector.
3. After this created this file:

   ```
   import mysql.connector

   mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
         host="localhost",
         user="yourusername",
         passwd="yourpassword",
         database="mydatabase"
       )

   mycursor = mydb.cursor()

   mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))")
   ```

   Then I run my code. I am getting below error:

   ```
   traceback(most recent call last)
   file "testdb.py" line7 in <module>
   database = "mydatabase"
   file "/home/shilpakala/last/lib/python2.7/site-package/mysql/connector/connection-cext.py line 78 in _i
   ```

   I'm getting:

   ```
   1045(2800)access denied for user yourusername@localhost(using password:yes)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you never set a password in mysql, it will not auth with a username and password.  It just lets you connect(bad).  First thing to do after you install any sql is set a root or db user password (common practice for postgres is the postgres user).  Then with that user, you can add other users and assign permissions to different databases if you're trying to run multiple services against one DB instance.

If you think you did set a root password [here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) how to reset it, so you can get started.